# Adding a scrollbar in vegalite

Tags: vega-lite, observablehq

I am drawing a horizontal stacked bar-plot involving many datasets and want to add a vertical scrollbar because displaying all at once is not space efficient. I am drawing it using vegalite in observable notebook. So, I am wondering how to include scrollbar in vegalite?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the same bar chart or a simple bar chart in hconcat having all the data but with a `selection interval params`. Then use the same param name to change the scales of original chart. So initially all the data will be visible but when you perform a selection on your simple bar chart it will give the effect of scrolling of bar chart.

Below is the sample code or refer [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/sp500.csv"},
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "height": 400,
      "width": 50,
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "fill": "lightgray"},
      "params": [
        {"name": "brush", "select": {"type": "interval", "encodings": ["y"]}}
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal", "sort": "-x"},
        "x": {
          "field": "price",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"tickCount": 3, "grid": false}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "height": 400,
      "width": 480,
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "scale": {"domain": {"param": "brush"}},
          "axis": {"title": ""}
        },
        "x": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Other way to add a basic scrollbar by giving `max-height` and overflow scroll to a div in which the chart is embedded.
Below is the snippet or refer [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wahab896/7z8ed4tv/26/):

```js
var yourVlSpec = {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "https://vega.github.io/editor/data/sp500.csv"},
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "height": 1400,
      "width": 300,
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {"title": ""}
        },
        "x": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
vegaEmbed("#vis", yourVlSpec, {renderer: 'svg'}).then(res => {
    var view = res.view;
  //console.log(view.data('source_0'));
});
```

```css
.vegaDiv{
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5.20.2/build/vega.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@5.0.0/build/vega-lite.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6.17.0/build/vega-embed.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="vegaDiv" id="vis"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! :) Firstly, the link of both the editors you have provided is not working. Can you check it once? It seems the first one doesn't work in mine example as I am using the row faceting and there are plenty of rows. For the second one, is it possible to do this in observablehq? I tried but I didn't figure out how to write that portion of vegaEmbed in observable notebook.

Comment: Ohh, I figured out using the second way in observablehq. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Have fixed my links in above responses. You haven't provided any sample or reproducible example in your question it was just mentioned that you have large dataset, so I don't know on what type of chart you were trying to achieve it thats why I added the possible scrolling options in my answer. Also I don't know how to add vega-lite on observablehq, so on that also I cannot support much.